# Encrypt a string in Java so that a C program can decrypt it, without any padding in the decrypted text?

Tags: java, c, encryption, aes

I am doing a simple AES encryption in Java:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getAES128SecretKey());
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input);
```

The output is converted to hex and stored in a database.

A later process (one written in C/C++) comes along and reads the hex, converts it to bytes and decrypts it.

The issue is apparently the C implementation correctly decrypts the text, but also keeps extra bytes at the end that are unnecessary.

For example (not real values):

```
Java: encrypt("eric") -> 1234567890FFFFFF1234567890FFFFFF  (hex)
Java: decrypt("1234567890FFFFFF1234567890FFFFFF") -> "eric"
   C: decrypt("1234567890FFFFFF1234567890FFFFFF") -> "eric XXXX XXXX XXXX"
```

I do not own the C decryption algorithm and the party using it has suggested I append a null terminator character `'\0'` to the Java bytes before encryption.  My question is, would that work and should I even entertain that idea?

Reading the first answer (while "unaccepted", it sounds correct to me) to the question [Padding error when using AES encryption in Java and decryption in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927380/padding-error-when-using-aes-encryption-in-java-and-decryption-in-c), an explicit encoding of the padding size seems to be the correct way to go about this.

However, what if the string is encrypted in C and decrypted in C? Will the C encrypted string now have issues when decrypted in C, and removing the padding as if it were a Java encrypted string?  Or would this be a non-issue?

Comment: Java and C in the same question. It's like comparing a Harley and a tricycle... Java is the tricycle.

Comment: @Matt - Java is at least as cool as one of them there Razor scooters all the hip kids are riding now-days... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption / decryption process is largely irrelevant. After all, what comes in should be the same as what comes out. The question is what do the bytes representing the String object look like when written to a file.

A quick test confirms that when java writes a string to a stream neither the string nor the stream are null terminated. Consider the following code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public SimpleStringIoTest
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    String message = "Raw Java String";
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("javaoutput.bin");
    fileWriter.write(message);
    fileWriter.close();
  }
}
```

Doing a hexdump of the file that it produces the following.

```
00000000  52 61 77 20 41 61 76 61 20 53 74 72 69 6e 67     Raw Java String
```

Therefore, when you encrypt that you end up with an 15 bytes of encrypted string and blocksize - 15 bytes of encrypted padding.  When you decrypt this you get not only the string but also the plain-text padding, and unless you know the length of the plain-text or have an embeded plain-text terminator there is no way to know where the plain-text ends.

Using NUL ('\0') as the terminator makes sense, because this is also the terminator that C uses to mark the end of  string. The ony possible problem is if NUL can somehow occur in your string already. Given that this would probably cause other issues with C/C++ programs I kind of doubt that, but you could always escape it away if it was a problem.

Oh, and I checked changing `messages` as follows:

```
String message = "Raw Java String\0";
```

Gives a hex dump of

```
00000000  52 61 77 20 41 61 76 61 20 53 74 72 69 6e 67 00  Raw Java String
```

Comment: thanks for the detail, appreciate the answer.  So, "Should I entertain adding a \0?" === not the right question. :)

Digging deeper into the code, it appears the C-impl used the size of the padding as the padding value.  The request to tack on a \0 was due to the fact that the developer did not know that was how to remove the padding - making the \0 unnecessary.

Comment: @Eric: Using the size of the padding as the padding value is fairly standard. The only problem is you end up with a potential collision cipher-text collision for different plain-texts. Consider the plain-texts "pad" and "pad1". If you assume a 32-bit block size, and lack of NUL terminator, they would encrypt to the same cipher-text. Given that cipher-text then, how do you know which is the right plain-text? You don't get this problem when you add the explicit terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Since AES is block cipher, you should pad data being encrypt to 16 bytes.
Since C code doesn't deal with padding, probably it would report an error while encrypting, or add 'default' padding.
Better, add padding by yourself.

Comment: @Eric: It seems like there isn't enough information to reliably fix this on the C side. Without a priori knowledge of the string length or a reliable terminator I don't think you can differentiate plain-text from padding.

Comment: Also, try to pass strings with length 1, 2, 3, 4... 15, 16, and see, what padding will be added by Java side.

Answer (score 1):

The String issue and NULL padding is a distraction and potentially irrelevant. Java uses standard padding schemes (PKCS#5) to *unambiguously* allow the decryptor to know how many bytes of the final block need to be discarded. The C side of this also uses some scheme. You need to know what that scheme is. I would avoid attempting something like padding with '\0' until you know the padding algorithm that is expected by the C decryptor.

You should also explicitly request the padding and mode in the `Cipher.getInstance()` method rather than relying on defaults. For example, your usage is equivalent to `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")` if you are using the Sun JCE provider, an excellent choice.

Comment: thanks, since we (by that I mean two different teams working on the same project) own both ends, I think we're good on finding a solution.  As long as everybody follows the PKCS#5 padding scheme for all encryptor/decryptor solutions, regardless of the language, we should be good to go.